# How to refresh js-select(multiselect)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, multi-select

This is my drop down

`@Html.DropDownList("users", null, "Display All", new { @class ="form-control js-select", Id = "users" })`

and this is,What I want to do

```
 $('#site').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetUserBySite", "Experiment")',
            data: { site: $('#site').val() },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (j) {
                console.log(j);

                $('select#users').empty();
                $.each(j, function (i, obj) {
                    var div_data = "<option value=" + obj.Value + ">" + obj.Text + "</option>";
                    $('select#users').append(div_data);

                });


            },
            error: function () {
                alert("something went wrong" );
            }
        });
    });
```

So I want to change the data of user dropdown list based on site dropdown selection. Its working fine if I don't use `js-select` class with dropdown but not working with that class.
Please give a solution so that I can use `js-select`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To refresh js-select use following code after a loop

```
  $('select#users').multiselect("refresh").multiselect('rebuild');
```